# Laravel 5.4 hasManyThrough with a second local key

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

The current state of the database

```
User
----
id 
name
```

```
UserCourse
----
id
user_id
course_id
```

```
Homework
----
id
course_id
name
```

**Details:** Users can subscribe to multiple courses and their subscription is held in the `UserCourse` table. Courses can have multiple homeworks.

**Question:** somebody wants to access all the homeworks from all the courses an user has subscribed to.

So one user hasMany subscriptions to courses and each course hasMany homeworks.
So the obvious solution is to use this code from the User Model.

`$this->hasManyThough('App\Homework', 'App\UserSubscribedToCourse', 'user_id', 'course_id')`,

*but this generates the following query*

`select homeworks.*, user_course.user_id 
from homeworks inner join user_course on user_course.id = homeworks.course_id where user_course.user_id = 51`

As you can see, it falsely thinks that it should match `user_course.id` with the foreign key `homeworks.course_id`, but the correct `localKey` should be `user_course.course_id`.

As far as I can see from the source code, only localKey for the User table can be specified.

This has been fixed in laravel 5.5 with this pull request: https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/19114

Is there a way to perform this in laravel 5.4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Access all the homeworks from all the courses an user has subscribed to.

Get all the courses the User has subscribed to

```
$user_id = Auth::user()->id;
$courses = UserCourse::where('user_id', $user_id)->pluck('course_id');
```

Get all the homeworks from the courses

```
$homework = Homework::whereIn('course_id', $courses)->get();
```